# Getting the product price of a WooCommerce product with Timber, Twig and ACF outside of WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm building a custom product loop outside of WooCommerce and I have setup a repeater loop within ACF where they can select the product they want to display and it returns the product's object; however this doesn't quite seem to match the same object you would get back with using the WC function `get_product`, as in, the price details are returned like this:

```
[_regular_price] => 14.99
[_sale_price] => 
[_price] => 14.99
```

These fields aren't accessible like many other fields as they start with an underscore.

The above data comes from a loop, such as:

```
{% for product in post.get_field('showcase_products') %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried doing `product.get_price` in Twig but it doesn't work.

I was then able to try doing the below:

```
{% set price = fn('wc_get_product', product.id) %}
```

Then I was able to use any of the below:

```
{{ fn('print_r', price.price) }}
{{ fn('print_r', price.get_price) }}
{{ fn('print_r', price.get_price_html) }}
```

Is there a way to be able to get the above data without the extra call to the WC function `wc_get_product` within each loop?

Comment: Official docs says they do the same thing - call `wc_get_product` in a loop (https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/woocommerce/#tease-product). For some reason Timber not getting context. So I guess at least for now the answer is no. Maybe in version 2+ it will be fixed (wirght now documentation is same on WC) or we'll need to make own research on that question.

Answer (score 0):

> however this doesn't quite seem to match the same object you would get back with using the WC function get_product

This is because the ACF repeater field is set to return WP_Post data in an array, even for the "product" post type. ACF doesn't convert each post in the repeater array to a Woocommerce product for you, so you have to do it manually on each loop as you have `{% set price = fn('wc_get_product', product.id) %}`

Even Timber uses the `wc_get_product` function in their docs here https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/woocommerce/

I don't think there's anything particularly wrong or resource heavy in converting each post in the array with that function.